# What is $\left\| u \right\|_{ H_{0}^{k}, H_{0}^{k}}$ norm when $H_{0}^{k}=\left\{u \in H^{k, 2}(M) \mid \int_{M} u \operatorname{vol}_{g}=0\right\}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

What is $\left\| f \right\|_{ H_{0}^{k}, H_{0}^{k}}$ norm when $H_{0}^{k}=\left\{u \in H^{k, 2}(M) \mid \int_{M} u \operatorname{vol}_{g}=0\right\}$.

I'm reading a paper
[Chern-Yamabe flow](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.04917.pdf)
which said that

**Now for $k$ big enough $(k>n)$, the first eigenvalue of the operator $-\Delta$ on the space $H_{0}^{k}=\left\{u \in H^{k, 2}(M) \mid \int_{M} u \mathrm{vol}_{g}=0\right\}$ is strictly negative hence $\left\|e^{-t \Delta}\right\|_{H_{0}^{k}, H_{0}^{k}} \leq$ $C_{0} e^{-c t}$.**

I have no idea what is $\left\| - \right\|_{ H_{0}^{k}, H_{0}^{k}}$ norm.

Comment: Taking $K:f\to (\Delta)^{-1}f$ as a (compact) operator between $H^k_0$ and $H^k_0$, it is the usual linear operator norm, perhaps?

Comment: @username given the context, your interpretation is almost certainly the correct one (that $\| e^{-t\Delta}\|_{H_0^k,H_0^k}$ is the operator norm of $e^{-t\Delta}$ as a mapping from $H^k_0$ to itself). Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: It seems that the $\Delta$ in this paper is $-\Delta$. I add the link in the question.

Comment: Oof, I don't like this notation. Normally for operator norms I would write $\| - \|_{X\to Y}$ because the one they chose, $\| - \|_{X,Y}$, does not make clear whether they want it to be the operator norm of a mapping from $X\to Y$ or from $Y\to X$. This becomes a bit of an issue later on when they write $\| e^{-t\Delta} \|_{H^k_0, H^0_0}$. At a quick glance it is not obvious to me which direction they meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial answer to your question. I would think it means:
$$
\sup\bigg(\| u(t,\cdot)\|_{H^k_0} : u(t,\cdot)=\exp(-t\Delta) u(0,\cdot),\textrm{ with } \| u(0,\cdot)\|_{H^k_0}=1\bigg).
$$